# Adding search criteria to the url, but can't go back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the parameters of my search criteria into the url so that it's possible to copy and paste the specific search.

Currently I have this:

```
 // Search criteria in the url
 var ready = function(e){
     $("#filterrific_filter").click(function(){
       $.get($("#filterrific_filter").attr("action"), $("#filterrific_filter").serialize(), null, "script");
       history.pushState(null, document.title, $("#filterrific_filter").attr("action") + "?" + $("#filterrific_filter").serialize());
       e.preventDefault();
     });
     $(window).bind("popstate", function() {
       $.getScript(location.href);
     });
 };
 $(document).ready(ready);
 $(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

The problem is: when a result is clicked on, and the users tries to go back to the search page again, they don't get back, they stay on the same page. The url changes though.

[Here is a video to display the problem](https://youtu.be/ZkInlULH4FI)

[And here is a link to the webpage, if you would like to test it yourself](http://www.rentapart.dk/apartments)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: my knowledge on history/pushstate/popstate is lacking, but I see a click on a filter creates 2 history entries. My guess would be that both ready and page:load events fire, so you also call your ready function twice, creating duplicate click handlers, duplicate pushstates etc.

Comment: I'm also seeing errors in your page, like bootstrap requiring jquery...

Comment: Yea, I fixed that on the local version, but it changes nothing in this matter, unfortunately..

Answer (score 0):

Try **removing** this whole section:

```
$(window).bind("popstate", function() {
  $.getScript(location.href);
});
```

Since your `apartments#show` action (a guess, assuming you're using a RESTful design in your Rails backend) is a round-trip request (not AJAX, like your filter), and your query string URL will run the filterrific scripts correctly on a reload, you might as well let the back button work the default way.

***Disclaimer: this is a shot in the dark without more context. If it doesn't work for you, and you provide more context, I'll happily revisit.***

Comment: That did not work - if I remove the other part, the url does not get updated, but then it works, so I assume the problem lies there.
Is there any context you can request that may help solving this problem?

Comment: What exactly did it do, when you tried my suggestion? Also, why do you need the second `$(document).on('page:load', ready);`? Like @yezzz's comment says, that likely is setting duplicate handlers, and may be contributing to the problem.

Comment: Nothing happened - the result is the same.
I have now tried to remove the `$(document).on('page:load', ready);` and now it only works if I refresh the page first, so I guess I need the last two lines?

Comment: Could you clarify "refresh the page first"? As in, you refresh then push back, or push back then refresh? Also, it seems to work now...did you try something else?

Comment: If I go to the search page /apartments nothing works, I have to refresh the page before anything happens when I click the buttons. And no, unfortunately i didn't do anything :-(